# Transaction problems with clustered Quartz invoking via JMX

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm setup Quartz 2.1.0 to run in Websphere in clustered mode, using JobStoreTX, I enable org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export so I can access quartz scheduler via JMX.

The problem is when I want to invoke some method via JMX which do something with sql I got exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: Failure obtaining db row lock: Not in transaction.
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdRowLockSemaphore.executeSQL(StdRowLockSemaphore.java:116)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.DBSemaphore.obtainLock(DBSemaphore.java:115)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.executeInLock(JobStoreCMT.java:238)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.removeTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1410)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.unscheduleJob(QuartzScheduler.java:1026)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.deleteJob(QuartzScheduler.java:934)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerMBeanImpl.deleteJob(QuartzSchedulerMBeanImpl.java:352)
```

It seems that all operation within scheduler needs to be enclosed into a transaction, but when invoke via JMX no transaction is present. How should I fix it ?

```
<property name="quartzProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">myApp</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold">60000</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">q</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.class">org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">5</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority">5</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck">true</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export">true</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.objectName">quartz:type=QuartzScheduler,name=JmxScheduler</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
```

UPDATE:

I am using spring so `JobStoreTX` is overrided to `LocalDataSourceJobStore`

UPDATE2

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSourceCron" jndi-name="jdbc/..." />



<bean id="scheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceCron" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true" />
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
    <property name="triggers" ref="jobTriggers" />
    <property name="jobDetails" ref="jobDetails" />
(properties)

</bean>
```

Comment: can you post the rest of your spring config?

Comment: could you post the code / configuration on how you are integrating Spring with JMX, how are you publishing the spring Bean in JMX

Comment: it is already here. I just add properties jmx.export to true and then MBean is exposed. And what u mean integrating with spring ? I am using SchedulerFactoryBean which is spring class inside my spring context

Answer (score 0):

The Spring transaction manager is active in the scope of a job launched via the application, but it's not active when the same job is trigerred via JMX.

How are you registering the Job to be launchable via JMX, can you post the code ?

The best way would be to use JMX Spring integration facilities, where a Spring bean can be registered via JMX, see the documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/jmx.html). There is [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/exposing-pojo-jmx-mbean-easily) an example of how to publish a Spring bean in JMX.

Comment: datasource is OK. When jobs are running inside app then everything works. Just when I want to invoke some operation via JMX then this problem occurs. And yes I am using Spring

Answer (score 0):

As the Quartz `Scheduler` is a managed spring bean, you could use spring's [declarative transaction management](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative) to make the `Scheduler` "transaction aware".

Making the `QuartzSchedulerMBeanImpl` "transaction aware" might be a cleaner approach but this is a bit more tricky as it isn't a managed spring bean. (it's created [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.1.0/org/quartz/core/QuartzScheduler.java#QuartzScheduler.registerJMX%28%29)). By registering & exposing the mbean yourself you could use spring's declarative transaction management to make it "transaction aware". Another approach would be to use [AspectJ](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj) to make the mbean "transaction aware".